# Parse relationships and searches specific pfQuery PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, pfquery, pfobject

I want to use as the backend of my app Parse, and suppose that I have a class with different restaurants, menus for each restaurant and for each menu different products, I have a class Place, Menu, Product and MenuItems:

The MenuItem class has:
Pointe menu
Pointer product

The Menu class:
Pointer place

Once chosen restaurant have to show all products for that restaurant:
My Code:

```
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Places"];
    [query whereKey:@"name" equalTo:PlaceSelect];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
        PFObject *Menu;
        if (!error)
        {
            for (PFObject *ob in objects)
            {
                Menu = ob;
            }
        }

        PFQuery *query1 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Menus"];
        [query1 whereKey:@"place" equalTo:Menu];
        [query1 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects2, NSError *error2) {
            PFObject *MenuItems;
            if (!error2)
            {
                for (PFObject *ob2 in objects2)
                {
                    MenuItems = ob2;
                }
            }

            PFQuery *query2 = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"MenuItems"];
            [query2 whereKey:@"menu" equalTo:MenuItems];
            [query2 selectKeys:@[@"product"]];
            [query2 findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects3, NSError *error3) {
                PFObject *Products;
                if (!error3)
                {
                    for (PFObject *ob3 in objects3)
                    {
                        Products = ob3;
                        NSLog(@" %@ ",Products);
                    }
```

I get related products but when I want to filter by type: drinks, starters, etc... It gives me all the products of all places them...

```
PFQuery *retrievedDrink = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Products"];
                    [retrievedDrink whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"drink"];
                    [retrievedDrink whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:Products.objectId];
                    [retrievedDrink findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                        DrinksArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:objects];
                        NSLog(@"numero de productos Drinks= %i ",[DrinksArray count]);
                    }];
```

Thanks in advance, if anyone knows a way to more efficiently please I would like to clarify my doubts

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of this line

`[retrievedDrink whereKey:@"objectId" equalTo:Products.objectId];`

That is returning all your objects.

You have a duplicate array of your objects that is not needed, and also, do an error check.

This should find all the drinks stored in your Parse class, store them in an array called `objects` and allow you to query that array in your `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock`

```
    PFQuery *retrievedDrink = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Products"];
                        [retrievedDrink whereKey:@"type" equalTo:@"drink"];
                        [retrievedDrink findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                         if (!error) {

                            NSLog(@"numero de productos Drinks= %i ",[objects count]);

                         }

                        }];
```